# Can I respond to a dialogue box via terminal? Or start up screen share from terminal?

Tags: networking, ssh, sharing

I can ssh into computer B from computer A, but when I want to share a screen it asks computer B for permission. Is there a way to respond to that dialogue box from an ssh in terminal?

The computer is not on the same local network. I am able to remote access into the computer, but I am having trouble opening the screen sharing. There is an application that only computer A can use.

Comment: "screen sharing" being what, exactly? are you referring to the default Ubuntu `vino-server` or something else?

Comment: is screen sharing on mac. I'm just trying to avoid vpn just to see if its doable from terminal